# Modeling beta-binomial distributed data using glmmTBM

Tags: r

Im trying to fit a mixed effect model to asses for effects upon the rate of germinated polen grains. I started with a binomial distribution with a model structure like this:

```
glmer(cbind(NGG,NGNG) ~ RH3*Altitude + AbH + Date3 + (1 | Receptor/Code/Plant) + 
                         (1 | Mountain/Community), data=database, family="binomial", 
                            control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

Where NGG is the number of successes (germinated grains per stigma, can vary from 0 to e.g. 55), NGNG the number of failures (non-germinated grains 0 to e.g. 80). The issue is, after seeing the results, data seems to be over-dispersed, as indicated by the function (found in http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/263877_d811720e434d47fb8430b8f0bb7f7da4.html):

```
overdisp_fun <- function(model) {
  vpars <- function(m) {
    nrow(m)*(nrow(m)+1)/2
  } 
  model.df <- sum(sapply(VarCorr(model), vpars)) + length(fixef(model))
  rdf <- nrow(model.frame(model))-model.df
  rp <- residuals(model, type = "pearson") # computes pearson residuals
  Pearson.chisq <- sum(rp^2)
  prat <- Pearson.chisq/rdf
  pval <- pchisq(Pearson.chisq, df = rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
  c(chisq = Pearson.chisq, ratio = prat, rdf = rdf, p = pval)
}
```

The output was:
        chisq = 1.334567e+04, ratio = 1.656201e+00, rdf = 8.058000e+03,             p = 3.845911e-268

So I decided to try a beta-binomial in glmmTMB as follows (its important to keep this hierarchical structure):

```
glmmTMB(cbind(NGG,NGNG) ~ RH3*Altitude + AbH + Date3  +  (1 | Receptor/Code/Plant) + 
                          (1 | Mountain/Community), data=database, 
                          family=betabinomial(link = "logit"), na.action = na.omit, weights=NGT)
```

When I run it.. says:
Error in nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control = control$optCtrl) : (converted from warning) NA/NaN function evaluation

Is there something wrong in the model writing? I already checked for posible issues in (http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/263877_d811720e434d47fb8430b8f0bb7f7da4.html) but did not find any solution yet.

thanks

Comment: Binomial models should not have outcomes that vary from 0 to 55 unless they are cumulative positives with a denominator that exceeds the counts. I'm thinking you may want a Poisson model.

Comment: But what I want to evaluate is the proportion of germinated grains; since I saw many models using the number of polen grains as "succeses" and non-germinated as "failure" (hence a proportion of succeses from a total amount of tries (no of grains)). I used a poisson for another model when I wanted to test for the "total number of polen grains". Here is the "rate of polen germinated".

Comment: Always the response variable (germinated ratio) is equal to or less than total number of grains (number of attempts). So a case where the response variable is 55, the denominator is equal (55, succes rate of "1") or exceeds the count (e.g. 55/80, 0.68 of succes rate).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sounds like it could be valid. Can also use counts as outcome in poisson model with log number of seeds per group as an offset. Now you need to provide a specific data example to support testing.

Comment: The issue is I dont know what that error means...if I am writing the model in the wrong way... or is to complex to run ...

Comment: There's no data for me to run this, and I'm not sufficiently adept at that particular function to have a ready-made list if things to check for that error. Have you considered posting in the R-SIG-mixed mailing list?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know whats that... Where can I post this??

Comment: Do a google search for "R-SIG-mixed mailing list".